Determine if the given linear mapping F is bijective
A linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ is defined by
$$
F(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (x_1 − x_2 + 2x_3, x_2 + 3x_3, x_3, 0).
$$
Examine whether the transformation F is bijective.
The first idea that came to me was checking for injection + surjection. Of course, via $\ker F$ and $\mathrm{Im} F$. Starting with the kernel. The appropriate linear combination is hence:
$$
(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\alpha(1,0,0,0) +\beta(-1,1,0,0) +\gamma(2,3,1,0) +\delta(0,0,0,0) 
$$
and the matrix is:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    1&-1&2&0&0\\0&1&3&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0
  \end{array}\right]
$$
Now, considering the fact that there is a $0$ column and $0$ row I am not sure on how to proceed. I know that in order for the mapping to be injective the $\ker F = \{0\}$ and when solving the system the solution is $\{0,0,0,0\}$.
My question lies in the $0$ set for $x_4$. Does that automatically mean that the mapping is not injective because many points (i.e. any value of $x_1, x_2, x_3$) can project to the same point? Or is the condition satisfied because the solution to the system is $\{0,0,0,0\}$?

Do you know the Rank-Nullity (aka Dimension) Theorem yet?

For this particular map, you don't need any theory: Quite clearly $F(0,0,0,1)=0$.

@J.W.Tanner
the question stated $R^4$to $R^4$ but someone edited it. Does the last $0$ mean that the solution to the kernel is $(0,0,0,x_4)$ because any value will go to $0$ hence the answer is non-trivial or?

@ArturoMagidin:   did you deliberately edit $F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ to $F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_3)$?

@J.W.Tanner I was fixing unicode and messed up. Thanks for pointing it out.

@mjork_:  I will delete my above comment because of the editing.  But yes $f(0,0,0,x_4)=(0,0,0,0)$ for all $x_4\in\mathbb R$, so $f$ is not one-to-one

@mjork_ I did put in an index error, my apologies; but note that I was removing non-MathJax within formulas. Please use MathJax, whose processing includes responsive design. Also, if half your formulas are in MathJax and half are not (as your first dispayed equation was), then they may display with different fonts and lead people to think that they represent different objects. Most mathematicians would think that a and $a$ may be distinct objects.

@ArturoMagidin okay I will be more careful in the future, thanks for the advice

This is overkill. It might be good practice for more complex problems if that is what you are going for, but in this case you do not need to do this much work.
Note that $x_4$ plays no role in the value of $F$. That means that the function cannot be injective, since $F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4')$ for any fixed $x_1,x_2,x_3$, even if $x_4\neq x_4'$. So we can simply note that $F(0,0,0,0)=F(0,0,0,1)$ (which also shows that $\ker(F)\neq\{\mathbf{0}\}$).
And note that every vector in the range has last coordinate equal to $0$, so the function cannot be surjective (as the image does not include $(0,0,0,1)$).
To answer your explicit question: the fact that the column corresponding to $x_4$ contains all zeroes tells you that $x_4$ is a free variable in the solution. It is no different from any other way in which the column does not contain a pivot/leading one. And of course, free variables in the solution of a homogeneous system tell you the system has infinitely many solutions (when you are hoping for exactly one, in order to yield injectivity).

thank you! I admit i may have overthought it all but I really appreciate the answer.
